# Taxes and childcare expenses deduction for a dual-income couple in Alberta?

Tags: canada, income-tax, tax-deduction, child-care

We live in Alberta and need to know if we should obtain a receipt for childcare.  We paid $2400 last year.  My common law husband made $49000 last year and I made $28500. Is this worth it?  Will our childcare provider be taxed as well?

Comment: Related question: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1034/child-care-expenses-how-much-deduction-can-be-claimed-on-tax-return-canada

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, child care expenses are deductible on the tax return of the spouse with the lower net income, and at your income level, a $2400 deduction would be worth a reduction in taxes of $600, on your 2011 tax return.

So if you'd like to reduce your taxes by **$600**, do ask for that receipt – and yes, a receipt is *required.*  Refer to Canada Revenue Agency's [Form T778 - Child Care Expenses Deduction for 2011](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/t778/t778-11e.pdf).  Quote:

> **Supporting documents** – The individual or organization who received the
>   payments must give you a receipt showing information about the
>   services provided. When the child care services are provided by an
>   individual, you will need the social insurance number of the
>   individual. Do not send receipts with your return, but keep them in
>   case we ask to see them. If you file your return electronically using
>   EFILE, show your receipts to your EFILE service provider.

Whether or not you get a receipt (and if you don't, you forgo the $600), your childcare provider is *still* required to declare their self-employment income, and their net income (i.e. after any costs incurred doing the business) would be subject to income tax.

If you think you'd be doing somebody a favor by not asking for a receipt, you'd potentially be helping somebody commit a tax fraud.